# Should I use a static list or a static method which creates and returns a list?

Tags: java, list, constructor, static

Tried to make it like user suggested

```
private final static List<CalendarBankHoliday> COL_BANK_HOLIDAY_LIST 
        = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(new CalendarBankHoliday(2016,Calendar.DECEMBER,26), 
        new CalendarBankHoliday(2016,Calendar.DECEMBER,27), new CalendarBankHoliday(2017, Calendar.JANUARY, 2),
        new CalendarBankHoliday(2017, Calendar.APRIL, 14),  new CalendarBankHoliday(2017, Calendar.APRIL, 17),
        new CalendarBankHoliday(2017, Calendar.MAY, 1),     new CalendarBankHoliday(2017, Calendar.MAY, 29),
        new CalendarBankHoliday(2017, Calendar.AUGUST, 28), new CalendarBankHoliday(2017, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25),
        new CalendarBankHoliday(2017, Calendar.DECEMBER, 26)
        ));
```

Comment: Does every instance of the class use the same list? If so, then you want a static class variable. As it's written, you are comparing a static method with an instance variable, which isn't quite comparable. In the end, it depends how this is to be used

Comment: If you ever make it a static variable, make sure it is final, make sure the list is unmodifiable (Collections.unmodifiableList()), and make sure its elements are immutable. Otherwise you're sharing mutable state with all your application, and that is a good path to disaster.

Comment: Oh, and don't create an anonymous subclass as you're doing. Just use `BANK_HOLIDAY_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(...))`

Comment: So, you're asking for advice, but don't care at all about the responses you get, right? Any code can take that list and sort it, modify it or clear it inadvertently. And you're still using that horrible anonymous subclass idiom.

Comment: I've tried to implement everything you have said after painful trial and error and lots of googling, however one thing I cant get it to do is the anonymous subclasses thing. I'd be grateful if you looked over it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be creating a list of predefined holidays and you want only one list. Therefore you should do something like this:

```
public class ListManager
{
    private static final List bankHolidayList = new ArrayList<>();

    private ListManager()
    {
        bankHolidayList.add(...);
    }

    public static List getList()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(bankHolidayList);
    }
}
```

This means that you will get a list that is immutable.

Comment: Will the list ever change?

Answer (score 0):

To return a list there is no need to use a static keyword, if you want to return a list at the time of creation of the method then do not use void, use an array list of the same type you want to return.

Example:

```
public class Test{

  public ArrayList<Integer> myNumbers()    {
  ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  numbers.add(5);
  numbers.add(11);
  numbers.add(3);
  return(numbers);
  }
}
```